# How can I upload a file via php?

Tags: php, html

I try to make a simple file uploader in php, but I fail already at the beginning.

This is the tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRCobMXhnyw

So at the beginning I should make a file **index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>File upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <from action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" value="upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and an **upload.php:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    print_r($file);
}
```

When I upload the file I should see on my screen:

```
Array ([name] => uploadme.txt [type/plain [tmp_name] => 
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpXkZIVD [error] => 0 [size] => 9)
```

But it is not working. If i click on "upload" there is just nothing happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've misspelt `form` in your opening tag.

Comment: Its working correctly you just need to move your uploaded file to some where in your server. Use `move_uploaded_file` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @ George: Oh my god, yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mistake :**

You are having typo in the `<form`

`<from action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

It should be as

`<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

It prevents you to submit the form

**What you should do :**

You're just printing the uploaded file, but you should move it to some folder like this.

```
$target_file = 'upload/'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

**Note :**

You should create a folder named as `upload` and it should have **read/write** permission.

So, Your code should look something like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>File upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" value="upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    print_r($file);
    $target_file = 'upload/'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello, I did exactly like you said, but no file will be uploaded in my ftp folder. I get this message with your code:

Comment: Array ( [name] => uploadme.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /is/htdocs/user_tmp/wp********/phpqtiBeL [error] => 0 [size] => 9 )

Comment: Yes, that's just the output. The uploaded uploadme.txt will be inside the `upload` folder

Comment: Have you created a folder named as `upload` ?

Comment: Yes the folder name is `upload`. But when I upload the text-file it keeps empty.

Comment: I can see that the text file moves inside the `upload` folder